# Graphics and Formatting Not Loading in WordPress on IIS

Tags: images, installation, formatting, iis, configuration

We have IIS 7.5 and we've installed WordPress (v3.3.1) through the Microsoft Web Platform installer (http://www.microsoft.com/web/wordpress).

All works fine when we load WP locally (e.g. http://localhost/mywordpresssite), the graphics load fine. But when I enter the IP address or hostname accessing the site from a machine other than locally, none of the graphics or formatting appear.

Is there some configuration I have to set to get this working?

I've noticed that all the graphics etc. are hard-wired to 'localhost', which explains why I'm losing the images when accessing from a remote machine. e.g.

```
http://localhost/mywordpresssite/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/headers/lanterns.jpg
```

Help!!

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: OK but this talks about moving a wordpress site...I just created a new one but none of the links/images are loading because they have static URLs pinned to localhost...

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change your domain URL is thus in desperate need of changing from `localhost` to a globally accessible IP/host. You have moved virtually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your WordPress Address and Site Address are correct under Settings > General. ie., if you want it to be viewable on another computer, this shouldn't say "localhost" anywhere...

Comment: So easy when you know how...DUH rookie mistake :) THANK YOU :)

Comment: Just keep in mind that URLs in content, etc. will still be hardcoded to `localhost` if you ever inserted them when under localhost. This solution is great for when you have had no chance to create any content yet, and is incomplete when dealing with existing content, menus, some plugin and theme settings, etc.

Comment: +1, Yes, there are times when some MySQL mojo is necessary when the settings weren't quite right to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the right solution, but I had the symptoms (styles and images not loading) in a different case:  Take a look at the XML generated by Wordpress for web.config. At least in some cases, it is incorrect.  I've worked it through in the multisite case (different from this case) and had to change Rule 4 action to point to url="{R:2}" and Rule 5 to point to url="{R:3}".

```
<rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
</rule>
<rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:3}" />
</rule>
```